# React: Why won't the variable 'names' show inside render?

Tags: reactjs

When the checkbox is checked, the practitioner's names are pushed into namesArray. Then I did namesArray.toString() and made it the variable 'names'. But it won't render... How can I fix it?

```
let names = '';

    const selectPractitioners = () => {
        let namesArray = [];
        practitioners.forEach(pract => {
            if (pract.select) {
                namesArray.push(pract.displayName)
            }
        })
        names = namesArray.toString();
        console.log(names)
    };
```

```
 return (
        <div className="lists-container">

            <div className="practitioners-list">
                {practitioners.map(pract =>
                    <p key={pract.id} >
                        <input type="checkbox"
                            onChange={e => {
                                let value = e.target.checked;
                                setPractitioners(
                                    practitioners.map(pract => {
                                        pract.select = value;
                                        return pract;
                                    })
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                        {pract.displayName}
                    </p>)}
                <button onClick={() => { selectPractitioners() } } >Select Practitioners</button>
               
                        <p> These are the working practitioners: { names } </p>

            <div/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the state for that

try something like this:

```js
import React, { useState} from 'react'


const Example = () => {
    const [names, setNames] = useState("");

    const selectPractitioners = () => {
        let namesArray = [];
        practitioners.forEach(pract => {
            if (pract.select) {
                namesArray.push(pract.displayName)
            }
        })
        setNames(namesArray.toString());
        console.log(names)
    };

...
```

Comment: To supplement: the reason you have to use state is because each render the `Example` function is called again, meaning all local variables are destroyed and created again (even the state consts). `useState` keeps track of what the value was last render plus any updates using `setNames` and assigns that to the new `names` const. A normal variable without `useState` will have no way to retain values between renders.

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanation, really appreciate it. If possible do consider adding this description in the answer edit 